# Changing font color and background image when hovering over button

Tags: html, css

For my navigation bar, I have several buttons. When hovering over a button, I want the background image to change and I want the font color to change. The background image is changing fine but I can't get the font color to change. I included both `.but1` and `.but2` to give an idea of what each of the buttons look like but so far I've only edited `.but1` for the hover text.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**CSS:**

```
#buttons {
width:665px;
background:url(images/bg_but.jpg) left top no-repeat;
text-align:center;
height:46px;
margin-left:450px;
}

#buttons a {
font-family:OVerlock, cursive;
font-size:20px;
display:block;
float:left;
height:34px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#303030;
padding-top:12px;
padding-left:0;
text-align:center;
}

.but1 {
background:url(images/but1-4.png) left top no-repeat;
width:134px;
}

.but1:hover {
color:#FFF;
background:url(images/but11.png) left top no-repeat;
}

.but2 {
background:url(images/but2.png) left top no-repeat;
width:132px;
}

.but2:hover {
background:url(images/but22.png) left top no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="but1"  title="">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="but2" title="">Projects</a>
    <a href="#"  class="but3" title="">Paintings</a>
    <a href="#"  class="but4" title="">About</a>
    <a href="#" class="but5" title="">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector `#buttons a` is more specific than `.but1:hover`, so it will take precedence.

Change it to `#buttons .but1:hover` and it will be more specific.

Comment: ...or add class .button to all buttons as well and place common styrning there. Will make your code more reusable and future proof.

Comment: @Henrik: How would it be more reusable and future proof?

Comment: @Guffa: Selecting by class instead of id will make it possible to style other instances of buttons with the same color and font-size for example. Using an id selector makes that harder since there can only be one instance of that id per page.

Comment: @Henrik: Yes, selecting by class makes it more reusable, but don't you think that it would be better to just change the id to a class instead of setting a class on every child element? The future proof part I don't get, though.

Comment: @Guffa: You're right about not changing the id, what I ment was to add an extra class to each button (but1, but2 etc) and place the styling selected by #buttons a{} on that class. Maybe I was unclear about the future proof part, all I ment was that the code will be easier to maintain this way since nothing has to be abstracted in the future, if for example s/he wants to place buttons with the same styling in any other dom element that the one with id of "buttons".

Answer (score 0):

simply add your important into `.but1:hover` like the code below

```
.but1:hover {
color:#FFF !important;
background:url(images/but11.png) left top no-repeat;
}
```