# How to set selected Image to Button

Tags: html, ios, css

I need to develop a functionality for normal state image and selected state image to the button. i did goggling but i can't find any where exact solution. I use below code

in HTML:

```
<button><img src="kitty_normal.png" /></button>
```

please help me for selected image (kitty_selected.png) to the button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing font color and background image when hovering over button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387146/changing-font-color-and-background-image-when-hovering-over-button)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will need to use CSS and JS to do so or just CSS, depends on your needs.

See here the simple code to do so:

http://jsfiddle.net/7Shv9/3/

Now, I am not quite sure why are you using an image inside a button as you didn´t specify but if you want to use the image as background or no text will be displayed just you the button background property, if no then proceed as you did and the code is small the same but targeting the image element instead of the button

JSFiddle show both approaches

HTML

```
<button id="myButton">My button</button>
```

CSS

```
#myButton
{
    background-image: url("http://www.picgifs.com/smileys/smileys-and-emoticons/hello-kitty/smileys-hello-kitty-779727.gif");
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}

#myButton:hover
{
    background-image: url("http://www.picgifs.com/smileys/smileys-and-emoticons/hello-kitty/smileys-hello-kitty-150863.gif");
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Lastly this question has been asked several times on SO, so please search first for current answers before posting a new duplicate one to keep the site as clean as possible.